# How to add multiple products to cart from outside magento directory using ajax

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-community

I am using ajax to add multiple products to cart. I am correctly getting required products ids, but couldnot add them to cart.

```
<?php
    include_once '../app/Mage.php';
    Mage::app();
    $basePath = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session', array('name'=>'frontend'));
    $id_str = $_REQUEST['id_str'];

    $Ids    = explode(',',$id_str);

    $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart'); 
    $cart->init();

    foreach ($Ids as $productId) 
    {
        //$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);

        $cart->addProduct($productId,1);
    }
    $cart->save(); 
    echo "1";

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the following line:

```
$session->setCartWasUpdated(true);

$cart->save();
```

You may also want to wrap the add to cart action in a try catch block

```
try {
    $cart->addProduct($id, $qty);
    $session->setCartWasUpdated(true);
    $cart->save();
} catch (Exception $e) {

// do something
}
```